# How do I aggregate joins?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, aggregate

I have three related tables:

```
Employee(EmployeeId, EmployeeName)

Skill(SkillId, SkillName)

EmployeeSkill(EmployeSkillId, EmployeeId, SkillId)
```

`EmployeSkillId` is an identity.

The rows in the database are the following:

#### Employee Table:

```
EmployeeId | EmployeeNumber | EmployeeName
---------- | -------------- | ------------
        1  |         10015  |  John Doe
```

#### Skill Table:

```
SkillId | SkillName
------- | ---------
     1  |  .NET
     2  |  SQL
     3  |  OOD
     4  |  Leadership
```

#### EmployeeSkill Table:

```
EmployeeSkillId | EmployeeId | SkillId
--------------- | ---------- | -------
             1  |         1  |      1
             2  |         1  |      2
             3  |         1  |      3
             4  |         1  |      4
```

If I have an employee who has three skills registered on `EmployeSkill`, I'd like to be able to have a result as the following:

```
John Doe, "Skill-1, Skill2, Skill-3"
```

That is, to concatenate the name of the skills for that employee into a single string.

I tried the following, but it isn't working.

```
var query = from emp in Employee.All()
            from es in emp.EmployeeSkills
            join sk in Skill.All() on es.SkillId equals sk.SkillId
            group sk by new {emp.EmployeeName} into g
            select new TestEntity
            {
                Name = g.Key.EmployeeName,
                Skills = g.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                                     (sb, grp_row) => sb.Append(grp_row.SkillName))
                          .ToString()
            };
```

The aggregated list of skill names is coming back empty.  How can I do this?

Comment: I've formatted the question for you.  Should give you an idea on how to get your future questions how you want it.

Comment: thanks Jeff M, I will definitely learn how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could do the join as part of the select:

```
var query = from emp in Employee.All()
            select new TestEntity {
                Name = emp.EmployeeName,
                Skills = string.Join(", ", 
                       (from es in emp.EmployeeSkills
                        join sk in Skill.All() on es.SkillId equals sk.SkillId
                        select sk.SkillName)) };
```

Now that's going to do the join separately for each individually, which isn't terribly efficient. Another option is to build a mapping from skill ID to skill name first:

```
var skillMap = Skill.All().ToDictionary(sk => sk.SkillId,
                                        sk => sk.SkillName);
```

then the main query is easy:

```
var query = from emp in Employee.All()
            select new TestEntity {
                Name = emp.EmployeeName,
                Skills = string.Join(", ",
                       emp.EmployeeSkills.Select(sk => skillMap[sk.SkillId]))};
```

Ultimately there are lots of ways of skinning this cat - for example, if you wanted to stick to your original approach, that's still feasible. I would do it like this:

```
var query = from emp in Employee.All()
            from es in emp.EmployeeSkills
            join sk in Skill.All() on es.SkillId equals sk.SkillId
            group sk.SkillName by emp into g
            select new TestEntity
            {
                Name = g.Key.EmployeeName,
                Skills = string.Join(", ", g)
            };
```

At this point it's quite similar to your original query, just using `string.Join` instead of `Aggregate`, of course. If all these three approaches come back with an empty skills list, then I suspect there's something wrong with your data. It's not obvious to me why your first query would "succeed" but with an empty skill list.

EDIT: Okay, here's a short(-ish) but complete example of it working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    public static List<Employee> All { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills
    {
        get 
        { 
            return EmployeeSkill.All
                           .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == EmployeeId);
        }
    }
}

public class Skill
{
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public static List<Skill> All { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeSkill
{
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public static List<EmployeeSkill> All { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Skill.All = new List<Skill>
        {
            new Skill { SkillName = "C#", SkillId = 1},
            new Skill { SkillName = "Java", SkillId = 2},
            new Skill { SkillName = "C++", SkillId = 3},
        };

        Employee.All = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { EmployeeName = "Fred", EmployeeId = 1 },
            new Employee { EmployeeName = "Ginger", EmployeeId = 2 },
        };

        EmployeeSkill.All = new List<EmployeeSkill>
        {
            new EmployeeSkill { SkillId = 1, EmployeeId = 1 },
            new EmployeeSkill { SkillId = 2, EmployeeId = 1 },
            new EmployeeSkill { SkillId = 2, EmployeeId = 2 },
            new EmployeeSkill { SkillId = 3, EmployeeId = 2 },
        };

        var query = from emp in Employee.All
            from es in emp.EmployeeSkills
            join sk in Skill.All on es.SkillId equals sk.SkillId
            group sk.SkillName by emp.EmployeeName into g
            select new
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Skills = string.Join(", ", g)
            };

        foreach (var result in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
{ Name = Fred, Skills = C#, Java }
{ Name = Ginger, Skills = Java, C++ }
```

Comment: hey Jon. thanks for replying so fast. It's weird, but both options return the Skills property as blank. And I'm sure it's not data, since just using the join and returning one row per Employee/Skill will work. Any ideas what could be causing the Aggregation not to work?

Comment: @silverCORE: That sounds very strange... if you add change to use something like "Skills = g.Count().ToString();" do you get the right number of skills? If all the approaches are giving the same odd result, that does sound like there's a data problem. If you could give a short but complete example, that would really help. I'll try to build one up myself.

Comment: let me paste the data I have Jon, and also try the g.Count thing. with your last example, the part that says "group sk.SkillName by emp.EmployeeName", apparently that makes trying to use g.Key.EmployeeName unfeasible. At least my intellisense is not picking it up.

Comment: @silverCORE: Yes, that should have been either grouping by emp, or grouping by emp.EmployeeName and then just using g.Key. I've edited the query, and also included a short but complete example which *does* work. I wonder whether you're just not managing to display the results correctly? I think the query is fine.

Comment: Jon, you are the man. Thank you for taking the time to help me out. Really appreciated.

Comment: @Jon, an update: Found out that g.Count.Tostring() using any of your choices did work, however when using the third option with string.Join(",", g) it returns null. but the problem appears to be due to the fact that I'm using Subsonic, not LINQ To Objects per se... instead of using Employee.All() and emp.EmployeSkills and Skills.All(), i brought all those records as List<> before the query, and used those lists instead of querying Subsonic Active record, and it works. Any idea why the same query wouldn't work when querying subsonic directly?

Comment: @silverCORE: Oh, well if you're not using LINQ to Objects, it's a *completely* different matter. It could be a Subsonic bug, or some unsupported scenario. Anything which is performing query translation to SQL is going to be much more like LINQ to SQL than like LINQ to Objects.

Comment: @Jon: gotcha. I'm still getting the hang of LINQ. By the way, I'm ordering C# in depth tomorrow. That had been on my to-do list for months and it only seems more fair now :) Thank you!

Comment: @silverCORE: Cool - hope it helps! You might want to check out my Edulinq blog series as well, by the way: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx